# Excel VBA - Creating new sheets and pasting stuff in raise 1004 Error

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue with the Excel VBA code below. I ONLY get a `1004 error` when the block that is commented out is active.

Error Result:

- the first sheet in the array is created, header row pasted in and Formatted correctly
- Second sheet created, NO header row pasted
- Error stops script at that point -> no further sheets created

I cant figure out what the problem is, can anyone help?

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("AGESTOCK")

Dim newSheets(1 To 4) As String
newSheets(1) = "CHEM - ALSO"
newSheets(2) = "LBS - LBLA"
newSheets(3) = "LBS - LBFG"
newSheets(4) = "Chemicals"
Dim sheetName As Variant

'Copy Header Row from ws1
ws1.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Copy

'Create New Worksheets
For Each sheetName In newSheets
    Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = sheetName

    'Paste Header Row
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    ' Autofit Columns & Zoom & Scroll
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 90
    ActiveSheet.Columns("A:Y").AutoFit
    ActiveSheet.Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 60  'Description
    ActiveSheet.Columns("E").ColumnWidth = 12  'WAS
    ActiveSheet.Columns("F").ColumnWidth = 12  'NOW

    'THIS IS THE SECTION THAT BREAKS IT
    'Format WAS, NOW, AVGCOST, VALUE to CURRENCY  
'    ActiveSheet.Columns("E").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"  'WAS
'    ActiveSheet.Columns("F").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"  'NOW
'    ActiveSheet.Columns("H").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"  'AvgCost
'    ActiveSheet.Columns("L").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"  'Value

Next sheetName
ws1.Activate
```

Comment: move ws1.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Copy into the for loop right before     ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select

Answer (score 0):

This is basically because Excel's copying and pasting from VBA is horrible. I'd suggest using the following as your macro instead. Note that I assign the range, and then copy it directly to the destination (no messy selection takes place). This makes things a lot more reliable, because Excel handles the whole copy operation, not Windows. I think. Certainly makes things work for me though.

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim newSheets(1 To 4) As String
    newSheets(1) = "CHEM - ALSO"
    newSheets(2) = "LBS - LBLA"
    newSheets(3) = "LBS - LBFG"
    newSheets(4) = "Chemicals"
    Dim sheetName As Variant
    Dim ws1 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rngCopyTarget As Excel.Range
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    'Copy Header Row from ws1

    Set rngCopyTarget = ws1.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow
    'Create New Worksheets
    For Each sheetName In newSheets
        Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = sheetName

        'Paste Header Row
        rngCopyTarget.Copy ActiveSheet.Range(rngCopyTarget.Address)

        ' Autofit Columns & Zoom & Scroll
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 90
        ActiveSheet.Columns("A:Y").AutoFit
        ActiveSheet.Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 60  'Description
        ActiveSheet.Columns("E").ColumnWidth = 12  'WAS
        ActiveSheet.Columns("F").ColumnWidth = 12  'NOW

        'THIS IS THE SECTION THAT BREAKS IT
        'Format WAS, NOW, AVGCOST, VALUE to CURRENCY
        ActiveSheet.Columns("E").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"  'WAS
        ActiveSheet.Columns("F").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"  'NOW
        ActiveSheet.Columns("H").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"  'AvgCost
        ActiveSheet.Columns("L").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"  'Value

    Next sheetName
    ws1.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: As an addendum, you'll make the workbook really big if you apply formatting to the entire column. It's a well known way to bloat workbooks. Try using `Range()` and specifying some usefully large number of cells instead, e.g. `ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E50000").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"`

Answer (score 0):

@Sorceri has the idea in his comment but, as it hasn't been posted as an answer I'll expand on it.

Your code is copying the header detail before you enter the loop. If you set your screen so you can see both Excel and the VBA editor windows. In the VBA editor click anywhere in your code and **press F8** - notice the yellow row highlight because that's the next line of code to be executed.

Keep pressing **F8** while watching the changes in the Excel window. The "marching ants" will appear after your copy command. When you have **F8**'d down to

`ActiveSheet.Columns("E").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"`

then swap back to Excel and select the AGESTOCK sheet - the marching ants will be there!

**In the VBA editor press F8** and *the ants are gone meaning that the clipboard has been cleared*. Certain Excel actions clear the clipboard but apparently setting column width isn't one of them and changing cell formats in a range definitely is. I tested it "live".

Then the solution is to move your:

`ws1.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Copy`

into your loop like:

```
'*** DON'T Copy Header Row from ws1 yet ***
'ws1.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Copy '**copies contents before 1st loop and is emptied
'when you change the cell format ***

'Create New Worksheets
For Each sheetName In newSheets
    Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = sheetName

    'Copy Header Row from ws1
    ws1.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Copy

    'Paste Header Row
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste '
```